# Issue with bounds checking a member std::array inside a const function

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I'm getting strange behavior bounds checking a member std::array with mingw (gcc 4.7.0) with the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class testClass
{
    std::array<int, 2> testArray;

    public:
        testClass();
        void func() const;

};

testClass::testClass() : testArray({{1, 2}})
{
}

void testClass::func() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        std::cout << testArray.at(i) << '\n' << testArray[i] << '\n';       
}


int main()
{
    testClass test;
    test.func();
}
```

Output is

```
0
1
0
2
```

The error seems to be related to optimization, as it only crops up when compiled with `-O`, I tried the individual flags enabled by `-O` but couldn't narrow it down any further. Making the function non-const also fixes the issue. Could this be a bug or am I missing something?

*edit

Narrowed it down, looks like a bug in the `const` version of `.at()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 2> const testArray = {1, 2};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        std::cout << testArray.at(i) << '\n' << testArray[i] << '\n';       
}
```

Same output as above compiled with `-std=c++11 -O` using mingw 4.7.0 on Windows Xp sp3 and Windows 7 sp1.

*edit 2

Same output again

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    typedef std::array<int, 2> Tarray;
    Tarray test = {1, 2};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        std::cout << const_cast<Tarray const*>(&test)->at(i) << '\n' << test.at(i) << '\n';     
}
```

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/b0d5b3c7398f7e1a2e36838f23fc943c works well.

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It produces [a different output](http://ideone.com/ZhIsS) for me...

Comment: g++ 4.8.0 (experimental), all codes works well with -O0 only. With other -O flags gives such warning: "<anonymous> is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]"

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with gcc 4.7 or a 4.8 snapshot, both on an ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of array header

```
#ifdef __EXCEPTIONS
  constexpr const_reference
  at(size_type __n) const
  {
return __n < _Nm ? 
       _M_instance[__n] : throw out_of_range(__N("array::at"));
  }
#else
  const_reference
  at(size_type __n) const
  {
if (__n >= _Nm)
  std::__throw_out_of_range(__N("array::at"));
return _M_instance[__n];
  }
#endif
```

Undef __EXCEPTIONS in main file(or change `#ifdef` to `#ifndef` in array) leads to correct output. I don't know, this is right solution or not, but it works.

**UPD:** I change the code in my array's header to

```
#ifdef __EXCEPTIONS
  constexpr const_reference
  at(size_type __n) const
  {
return __n < _Nm ? 
       _M_instance[__n] : (throw out_of_range(__N("array::at"))),
                          _M_instance[__n];
   /*return __n < _Nm ? 
            _M_instance[__n] : throw out_of_range(__N("array::at"));*/
  }
#else
  const_reference
  at(size_type __n) const
  {
if (__n >= _Nm)
  std::__throw_out_of_range(__N("array::at"));
return _M_instance[__n];
  }
#endif
```

Now everything is working correctly

Comment: The bug in the unpatched header is that `__n < _Nm ? _M_instance[__n] : throw out_of_range(__N("array::at"))` evaluates to a prvalue temporary (because a conditional operator must evaluate to a prvalue if one of the operands is a `throw` expression - C++11 5.16/2). This temporary's lifetime is only until the end of the full expression of the `return` statement (C++11 12.2/5).  So the `at()` function returns a const reference to something that is no longer valid - the result is undefined behavior.

Comment: a horrible bug (`return a? b:throw c;`) --- wouldn't have thought that this sort of beginners error comes with any shipped c++ container.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I think it may be worth an answer of its own!

Comment: @Walter, why do you think it's a beginner's mistake? There's nothing inherently wrong with `(return a? b:throw c;) `, if the function didn't return by reference that would be fine. It was written that way on purpose to allow `array::at` to be `constexpr` (but as Michael points out, it doesn't work.)